# show data from date column - parse to date

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to show a table with a "Date" column in postgres.
I guess it has something to do with parsing string to date. I tried using simple date format but I'm un successful.

I actually posted similar question before and tried the suggestions given to but I'm still unsuccessful. I'll appreciate it if anyone can give me a sample using my codes below.

I can't parse string to date and show the data... below are my codes.

myDAO

```
package source;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


public class parseDAO {

    private Database database;

    public parseDAO(Database database) {
        this.database = database;

    }


    public List<parseBean> results() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        String querystring = "select * from dateparse";
        List<parseBean> result_array = new ArrayList<parseBean>();

        try {

            connection = database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(querystring);


            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                parseBean resultsarray = new parseBean();
                    resultsarray.setDate(resultSet.getDate("date"));
                    resultsarray.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                    resultsarray.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));

                result_array.add(resultsarray);
            }
        } finally {
            try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        return result_array;
    }
}
```

myServlet

```
package source;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class parseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private parseDAO parseDAO;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDB";
        String username = "postgres";
        String password = "secret";


        Database database = new Database(driver, url, username, password);
        this.parseDAO = new parseDAO(database);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {




            try {
            List<parseBean> result_array = parseDAO.results();

            request.setAttribute("result_array", result_array);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
            catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot retrieve areas", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the type in your database? If it's a date/time type, why are you calling getString?

Comment: So why are you calling getString?

Comment: yup it is a date... that's what I need help from.. If I call it using date I get an error. maybe you can help me with this

Comment: and what error do you get when you call `getDate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parseBean` class, change

```
private String date;
```

to

```
private Date date; // Note: java.util.Date, NOT java.sql.Date!
```

and change

```
resultsarray.setDate(resultSet.getString("date"));
```

to

```
resultsarray.setDate(resultSet.getDate("date"));
```

When presenting this in JSP, use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) with a specified [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${parseBean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, work on your [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) as well. Classnames should start with uppercase. Rename `parseBean` to `ParseBean`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC and I'm glad your back it is working now... BTW I have a follow up question.. Using the same situation how can I add "Date" parameters from a textfield...